# How to accept different data types from user simultaneously using list comprehension in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to accept different data types from user using list comprehension in python 3
This is my code with for loop -

> ```
> stuRecords = []
>     for i in range(1, num+1):
>         print('Enter the name and marks of {} student.'.format(i))
>         name = input()
>         marks = int(input())
>         stuRecords.append([name,marks])
> ```

How can I write this code using list comprehension. I have tried this -

```
stuRecords = [[name,marks] for name,marks in input(f'\nEnter the name and 
             marks of {num} students').strip().split()][:num]
```

But I get this error -

```
Enter the name and marks of 2 students...John
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HR_NestedList.py", line 13, in <module>
    stuRecords = [[name,marks] for name,marks in input(f'\nEnter the name and marks of {num} students...').strip().split()][:num]
  File "HR_NestedList.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    stuRecords = [[name,marks] for name,marks in input(f'\nEnter the name and marks of {num} students...').strip().split()][:num]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: But why do you `split` in the list-comp? This doesn't match the input format from the regular loop. According to your original code it should simply be: `stuRecords = [[input(), int(input())] for _ in range(1, num+1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
num = 3

stuRecords = [[[name, int(marks)] for name, marks in
               [input(f'Enter the name and marks of {i}th students:\n').strip().split()]][0]
              for i in range(1, num+1)]

print(stuRecords)
```